# Analytical Solution of Picewise-Non linear 4th order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, step-function

I'm strugling for a while on that. Is there a way to approach analytical the following BVP?
$$
\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}+[4\lambda_1^4H(y)+4\lambda_2^4H(-y)]y=0
$$
Where $H(x)$ stands for the Heaviside Step function. i.e. the wavelength changes with respect to the sign of the solution $y(x)$. $C^{(4)}$ continuity must hold.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can find solutions, locally, when assuming the initial conditions are $y(0)>0$ or $y(0)<0$ then it connect the solutions together depending on the sign changes with each respective solution.

Comment: Well, in the specific problem I'm solving, separate solutions are:
$$
y_1=A_1 e^{\lambda_1 x}\sin(\lambda_1 x+B_1)\\
y_2=A_2 e^{\lambda_2 x}\sin(\lambda_2 x+B_2)
$$ 
I'm not exactly sure how to connect them because there will be an "effective" wavelength $\lambda_{eff}$ which unfortunately is not the harmonic mean like in the 2nd order form of the same problem.

Comment: Supposing a positive initial condition, you know the solution is $y_1$ until $x = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}(-B_1 + \frac{\pi}{2}(2 k + 1))$ for some $k$ depending on the constant $B_1.$ At that cross-over point, you know that the solution drives it to be negative, so the rest of the solution has to solve the negative case of your DE. So you then have a new initial condition to drive the next solution. Repeat and there probably is a pattern you'll observe in the crossovers allowing for a solution in terms of Heavisides.

Comment: Well maybe it is not so simple. When I solve the equation numerically I'm always getting a shift in both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ that appear in the solutions. Maybe there is some frequency shift showing up from the other orders similarly to the damped oscillator.